# Passing pointed object by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have this function:

```
int foo(bar const&);
```

I want to use it like this:

```
bar a;
foo(a);
```

Here no copy of a will be happened.

But if I call it like this:

```
bar* a = new bar(); //not about dynamic allocation, I know it is not good
foo(*a);
```

At `foo(*a);`, will I loose some performance? Like unnecessary copy?

Comment: Add according output to the copy-constructor to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No copy will happen in either case. You can easily confirm that for instance by deleting the copy constructor of `bar`:

```
bar(bar const&) = delete; // cannot be copied
bar& operator=(bar const&) = delete; // cannot be reassigned
```

This would lead to a compiler error in case any bar object is being copied.

Answer (score 1):

No, there won't be a copy. Given a value `a` of type `T*`, the expression `*a` has type `T&` - i.e. you're passing a reference.